# Fragment not attached to Activity when receiving callback from DialogFragment after rotating device

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating an application that allows a user to upload a image from the gallery or to take a photo using the device camera. When clicking the appropriate button a Dialog appears and the user can select 'Take a photo' or 'Select an Image'. This all works fine, the problem is when I rotate the device while the Dialog is on screen then select an option the app crashes with an `IllegalStateException` saying that my Fragment is not attached to Activity. I've included the Dialog I'm using to communicate back to the target fragment:

Creating the DialogFragment:

```
public void onClick() {
    // Display a Dialog for choice between pick/ take picture
    ListDialogFragment dialogFragment = ListDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.take_photo, R.array.add_picture_options_array);
    dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Moo");
}
```

The DialogFragment class:

```
public class ListDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TITLE_RESOURCE_ID = "title_resource_id";
private static final String ARRAY_RESOURCE_ID = "array_resource_id";

private DialogItemSelectedListener listener;

public interface DialogItemSelectedListener {
    void onTakePhotoSelected();

    void onSelectImageSelected();
}

public ListDialogFragment() {
    // Default empty constructor
}

public static ListDialogFragment newInstance(@StringRes final int titleResourceId, @ArrayRes final int arrayResourceId) {
    ListDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ListDialogFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(TITLE_RESOURCE_ID, titleResourceId);
    bundle.putInt(ARRAY_RESOURCE_ID, arrayResourceId);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return dialogFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        listener = (DialogItemSelectedListener) getTargetFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling Fragment must implement DialogItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final int title = getArguments().getInt(TITLE_RESOURCE_ID);
    final int listItems = getArguments().getInt(ARRAY_RESOURCE_ID);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle(title).setItems(listItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    listener.onTakePhotoSelected();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    listener.onSelectImageSelected();
                    break;
                default:
                    dismiss();
            }
        }
    }).create();
}
```

}

The fragment implements the `DialogItemSelectedListener` and tries to go the following when `onTakePhotoSelected()` is called:

```
private void takePicture() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Here, we make sure that an Activity to handle the Camera Intent actually exists
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // This is where the photo itself will actually go
        imageFile = null;
        try {
            imageFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Could not create the file
        }

        // At this point, we can safely assume that the file was created successfully
        if (imageFile != null) {
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

The Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
    attachFragment();
}

private void attachFragment() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, TestFragment.newInstance()).commit();
}
```

}

The app crashes when calling `startActivityForResult();`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyTestFragment{22b2a6a0} not attached to Activity
```

What am I doing something wrong here; is this behaviour to be expected?
I've already tried `setRetainInstance(true);` but this does not work.

Comment: Try changing `getFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager` as you are opening the dialog from within a fragment and not from an Activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that each time orientation changes, you're creating a new instance of Fragment. And only one of them is actually attached to the Activity. Try this

```
    public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TestFragment testFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
        attachFragment(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void attachFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           testFragment = TestFragment.newInstance();
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.fragment_container, testFragment, "testFragment").commit();
        } else {
           testFragment = (TestFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("testFragment");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` ;
2. Do not use `setTargetFragment()` and `getTargetFragment()`, use `getParentFragment()` in the DialogFragment instead.

This worked in my case, but I should note that I only pass values to the fragment using its `onActivityResult()` method.